# Counting number of ways I can have unique numbers in array

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to find the number of ways to construct an array such that consecutive positions contain different values.

Specifically, I need to construct an array with elements such that each element 1 between  and k , all inclusive. I also want the first and last elements of the array to be  1 and x.

Complete problem statement:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
 def countArray(n, k, x):
    # Return the number of ways to fill in the array.
    if x > k:
        return 0
    if x == 1:
        return 0
    
    def fact(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        fact_range = n+1
        T = [1 for i in range(fact_range)]
        for i in range(1,fact_range):
            T[i] = i * T[i-1]
        return T[fact_range-1]
    
    ways = fact(k) / (fact(n-2)*fact(k-(n-2)))
    return int(ways)
```

In short, I did `K(C)N-2` to find the ways. How could I solve this?

It passes one of the base case with inputs as `countArray(4,3,2)` but fails for 16 other cases.

Comment: @VFX I tried this. I pass one of the base cases when inputs are countArray(4,3,2)

Comment: What's your explanation behind ```(K)C(N-2)```? That seems incorrect

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Number of ways to select the remaining positions from K numbers.

Comment: When the arrangement of numbers is important here, why would a combination work rather than a permutation?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Do not know how to use it here.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I know that. Did not understand the way it has been presented there.

Comment: Don't keep the link to the problem secret.

Answer (score 3):

Let `X(n)` be the number of ways of constructing an array of length n, starting with 1 and ending in x (and not repeating any numbers). Let `Y(n)` be the number of ways of constructing an array of length n, starting with 1 and NOT ending in x (and not repeating any numbers).

Then there's these recurrence relations (for n>1)

```
X(n+1) = Y(n)
Y(n+1) = X(n)*(k-1) + Y(n)*(k-2)
```

In words: If you want an array of length n+1 ending in x, then you need an array of length n not ending in x. And if you want an array of length n+1 not ending in x, then you can either add any of the k-1 symbols to an array of length n ending in x, or you can take an array of length n not ending in x, and add any of the k-2 symbols that aren't x and don't repeat the last value.

For the base case, `n=1`, if `x` is `1` then `X(1)=1`, `Y(1)=0` otherwise, `X(1)=0`, `Y(1)=1`

This gives you an O(n)-time method of computing the result.

```
def ways(n, k, x):
    M = 10**9 + 7
    wx = (x == 1)
    wnx = (x != 1)
    for _ in range(n-1):
        wx, wnx = wnx, wx * (k-1) + wnx*(k-2)
        wnx = wnx % M
    return wx

print(ways(100, 5, 2))
```

In principle you can reduce this to O(log n) by expressing the recurrence relations as a matrix and computing the matrix power (mod M), but it's probably not necessary for the question.

### [Additional working]

We have the recurrence relations:

```
X(n+1) = Y(n)
Y(n+1) = X(n)*(k-1) + Y(n)*(k-2)
```

Using the first, we can replace the `Y(_)` in the second with `X(_+1)` to reduce it down to a single variable. Then:

```
X(n+2) = X(n)*(k-1) + X(n+1)*(k-2)
```

Using standard techniques, we can solve this linear recurrence relation exactly.

In the case x!=1, we have:

```
X(n) = ((k-1)^(n-1) - (-1)^n) / k
```

And in the case x=1, we have:

```
X(n) = ((k-1)^(n-1) - (1-k)(-1)^n)/k
```

We can compute these mod M using Fermat's little theorem because M is prime. So 1/k = k^(M-2) mod M.

Thus we have (with a little bit of optimization) this short program that solves the problem and runs in O(log n) time:

```
def ways2(n, k, x):
    S = -1 if n%2 else 1
    return ((pow(k-1, n-1, M) + S) * pow(k, M-2, M) - S*(x==1)) % M
```

Comment: You may also notice that `T(n)`, the total number of sequences, is `X(n) + Y(n) = (n-1) ** (k-1)`, and simplify `Y(n+1) = X(n) + (k-2)T(n)`, which gives a more direct recursion: `X(n+1) = X(n-1) + (k-2)T(n-1) = X(n-1) + (k-2)*(n-2)**(k-1)`.

Comment: @user58697 or this seems easier: `X(n+1) = Y(n) = T(n) - X(n) = (n-1)**(k-1) - X(n)`. It's not really simpler though (to compute), because you need to compute all those powers.

Comment: @user58697 to reduce to a recurrence relation with a single variable, it seems quite nice to use the Y(n+1) relation in my question, and just substitute Y(_) for X(_+1). That gives X(n+2) = X(n)*(k-1) + X(n+1)*(k-2). Then I guess it's possible to find a closed form (ala Binet's formula) since this is a linear recurrence relation.

Comment: No need for Fermat: `pow(k, -1, M)`.

Comment: Well, since Python 3.8, so since October 2019. Appears to be faster as well, according to [these benchmarks](https://leetcode.com/problems/fancy-sequence/discuss/981528/O(1)-1-liners-for-all-with-explanation/796735) (not that that matters here).

Answer (score 0):

could you try this `DP` version:  (it's passed all tests) (it's inspired by @PaulHankin and take DP approach - will run performance later to see what's diff for big matrix)

```
def countArray(n, k, x):
    # Return the number of ways to fill in the array.
    big_mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
    dp = [[1], [1]]
    if x == 1: 
        dp = [[1], [0]]
    else:
        dp = [[1], [1]]
    
    for _ in range(n-2):
        dp[0].append(dp[0][-1] * (k - 1) % big_mod)
        dp[1].append((dp[0][-1] - dp[1][-1]) % big_mod)
    return dp[1][-1]
```

Comment: It's simple enough? Yes, sure, you still have to work out?  Don't appreciate others help will hinder/discourage people to help....in the future.